# What the meaning of ‘drove by’?

Tags: meaning

Four officers drove by in a car while he stood to attention and saluted.    What is the meaning of ‘drove by’?

Comment: It means they passed him in the car

Comment: "Drove" is the past tense of "drive".

Comment: What does the dictionary say?

Comment: Incidentally, he would have [*stood **at** attention*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand%20at%20attention) (not *to* attention).

Answer (score 1):

Drove is simple past tense, `drove by` in your sentence means they passed him in the car